# Buffered store produces errors in ExtJS 6.2

Tags: javascript, extjs

I cannot make buffered store work in my application. When I open my grid with a buffered store for the first time, I see that it triggeres two requests to the server side and gets 200 rows overall. However, when I scroll down to the bottom, I see no requests, event though the total number is much more than 200 rows. This is how my store is configured:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.BufferedStore', {
    fields: fields,
    autoLoad: true,
    leadingBufferZone: 100,
    pageSize: 100,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: "controller/MapsHandler.php", 
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'GET'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'items',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        },
        extraParams:{action: "getGridData"}
        }
    });
```

I thought that I did something wrong, but when I checked the official [example](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/classic/grid/buffered-store.html), I also got an error. This is how it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, when I scroll down, one and the same error pops up:

> TypeError: c is undefined

And the grid is not populated with data.

Comment: The problem in the example is an issue with the remote server script because it calls the callback with no data.

Comment: And why does it happen so randomly? When I scroll down, I see, that sometimes this error pops up after one request, but sometimes after some N requests?

Comment: From memory it was something to do with the encoding in the data for particular pages.